# How to get row count in asp.net and transfer asp.net row count to javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to get the value of an asp.net variable to javascript. Firstly, i wanted to get the number of rows in my database using asp.net and entity framework. Here is the query:

```
getRowCountThmb = (from g in obj.thumbnailImages where g.instrumentItem.brand.name == stringInstrumentName && g.instrumentItem.model == stringInstrumentModel select g).Count();
```

And then, the retrieved row count will be passed on to the getRowCountThmb property which is like this(auto-implemented): **public int getRowCountThmb { get; set; }**. And after that, i will get the value of getRowCountThmb in javascript like this: **var srcArray = "<%= getRowCountThmb %>";**

The problem is, I have found out that the getRowCountThmb is not actually getting any row count in the database. The value is 0. Resulting to a NaN value in the javascript variable called scrArray. Kindly give advice or provide solutions for this.

Comment: A value of `0` should not cause a `NaN`. And not getting any rows has nothing to do with javascript.

Comment: as @VDWWD said, NaN shouldn't be caused by row count returning zero. Could you add your code to your question ?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you put `getRowCountThmb` in quotation marks when injecting it (whether its value is 0 or not does not matter), making `srcArray` a string. NaN stands for "Not a Number", which is correct in this case.

Essentially, what you end up having in your source code is:

```
var srcArray = "0"; // <-- This is not a number, but a string (NaN)
```

You can solve this by removing the quotes like so:

```
var srcArray = <%= getRowCountThmb %>;
```